# Rails Activerecord query for joining multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Models

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
end
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end
```

I want to get a list of all comments under every post created by every User under this AdminUser.

To get all comments under every post done by 1 user is easy. I would use something like

```
comments=Comment.joins(:post).where("posts.user_id= ?",userid.to_s )
```

But here I need to go one more level up. ie get comments from every post made by every user under 1 admin_user.  I have never used more than one join before, so I am a bit confused.

If I could use **Activerecord association** inside strings it might look like

```
        comments=Comment.joins(:post).joins(:user).where("posts.user.admin_user.id=?",adminuser_id)
```

But I cannot use **posts.user.admin_user**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like

```
Comment.joins(post: :user)
```

Comment: I assumed, comment belongs to post and post belongs to user. Thats why.

Comment: Yes this was the join I was looking for. My final query was Comment.joins(post: :user).where("user.admin_user_id=?,admin_id)

Comment: I did. It was -ve earlier. thats why its showing 0.

Answer (score 2):

how about we first fetch the ids of users which belongs to admin user and then used to them to pick the comments using your query.

```
user_ids = admin_user.users.pluck(:id)
comments=Comment.joins(:post).where("posts.user_id IN  (?)", user_ids )
```

I have assumed that your query you pasted in question will work.

Comment: This works and thanks for answering... But I was looking to learn how to do it in 1 statement, as well as learning multiple joins in the process. Please let me know if there is a way to do it in 1 line. Thanks again...

Comment: may be im wrong but i think here it will requires inner query in which we will fetch the user_ids: post.user_id IN (inner query in which we fetch the users related to admin). bcoz we need to match the posts.user_id with all the user_ids against that admin. im not that good in the raw sql.:( i would help you to do this in one this way : `comments=Comment.joins(:post).where("posts.user_id IN  (?)", admin_user.users.pluck(:id))`